# How to Get a List of All Root / Main Installed Packages on Debian

Tags: debian, aptitude, packages

Is there a way to get all "main" packages that were installed via aptitude in Debian? By "main" I mean the package names that were given to aptitude via the install command. The equivalent of a Gentoo "world" file.

To my knowledge you can only get a list of all installed packages, included dependencies (about which I don't really care from a certain point of view). The only other way I could think of is to parse the bash_history file for aptitude install commands.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`aptitude` considers packages that are installed due to dependencies to be "*automatically*" installed. With that knowledge, you can quickly construct an [aptitude search pattern](http://algebraicthunk.net/~dburrows/projects/aptitude/doc/en/ch02s03.html) to list all installed packages that were not automatically installed:

```
aptitude search "?and(?installed, ?not(?automatic))"
```

Or, using the short form of the search terms:

```
aptitude search '~i !~M'
```

(Note that `!` is a special character in some shells. In the above, I used `'...'` as quote chars to make *Bash* happy.)

Finally, packages which were installed by basic system installation will also be listed in the above. If that's a problem, you can exclude packages which the system considers to be essential by adding an `!~E` filter. Or you could create a list of packages right after what you consider to be the basic installation, and `diff` against that.

(grepping through bash history is certainly also a quick and simple option, and will work well if you are mainly interested in uninstalling some recently-installed packages. However, due to the limited size of the bash history, you will have a tough time finding packages that were installed, say, a year ago.)

Comment: This also shows other packages, e.g. over 70 libraries.

Comment: Yeah, those were most likely installed during system setup. I added a paragraph explaining this.